# Problem to store values from Arduino MKR 1010 to mysql?

Tags: arduino-mkr

I have problem to store values to MySQL table from Arduino MKR 1010 Wifi.
I get the following message.

```
trying
got: 0 retrying
trying
got: 0 retrying
ERROR!
```

I have also tried to turn off firewall without success.
Is my code wrong? Can someone help me with this issue?

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
#include <MySQL_Encrypt_Sha1.h>
#include <MySQL_Packet.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <dht.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <wifiinfo.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

#define DHT22_PIN 7     
#define DHTTYPE 22
DHT deviceMonitor(DHT22_PIN,DHTTYPE) ;

IPAddress server_addr(192,168,86,39);  // IP of the MySQL *server* here
char user[] = "root";              // MySQL user login username
char password2[] = "test1234";        // MySQL user login password

char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        // your network SSID (name)
char password[] = SECRET_PASS;    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the Wifi radio's status

float hum; 
float temp;
float humError; 
float tempError;
int checkTemp;

char INSERT_DATA[] = "INSERT INTO weather (temp, hum) VALUES ('%s','%d')";
char query[128];
char temperature[10];

EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

void setup() {
  //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect
  Ethernet.begin(mac_addr);

  // attempt to connect to Wifi network:
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to network: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data:
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  
  Serial.println("----------------------------------------");
  printData();
  Serial.println("----------------------------------------");

  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) 
  {
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
     Serial.println("Mysql connection failed.");
  }
    }

void loop() 
{
  delay(5000);
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password2)) {
 
    MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
    checkTemp = deviceMonitor.read(DHT22_PIN);
    hum = deviceMonitor.readHumidity();
    temp = deviceMonitor.readTemperature();
    Serial.println((String)"Temperature: " + temp + " Celsius");
    Serial.println((String)"Humidity: " + hum +"%");
    Serial.println();
    sprintf(query, INSERT_DATA, temp, hum);
    cur_mem->execute(query);
    delete cur_mem;
    Serial.println("Data recorded.");
    delay(10000);
 }
 else
 {
   Serial.println("ERROR!");
 }
}

void printData() 
{
  Serial.println("Board Information:");
  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Network Information:");
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI):");
  Serial.println(rssi);

  byte encryption = WiFi.encryptionType();
  Serial.print("Encryption Type:");
  Serial.println(encryption, HEX);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Your output listing seems to have nothing to do with the the code you're apparently trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

I granted full right to user root in MySQL and now got this error instead.

```
ERROR: Timeout waiting for client.
Error: -1 = Mysql connection failed.
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Not an answer..